# Server to server communication in java - load balancing

Tags: java, chat

I have a chat application in java using nio it's working fine now. I want to split my chatserver into 2 with the same portno.

Simply :

1. I want to Split single my server into two or three. When client
   logins, it first connect to the first server.
2. When the **first server** have 10 clients then 11 th  client must
   connected to the **Second server**. and same mechanism for **third
   server**.
3. These three server must  have same port no.
4. These server must have an internal communication. If client 1 is
   logged into the server 1 . Any details got in **server 1** should be
   known by **Server 2** and **Server 3**.
5. A client in server 1 must have to  communicate with clients which
   are in server 2 and server 3.

How can I make these possible is there any example related to this. I googled it but couldn't find any appropriate solutions.

please guide me to resolve these.

Thank you very much.

Comment: regarding your 4th requirement, i think you would need a shared database or something like that so that all servers are in sync.

Comment: @Sikorski  you mean a temperory table, when client login the details will wright to that table. if so it will be accesable for all server and will get deleted when client logout. if  at a time 5k clients login into server it may take lot of time( if am wrong plz correct me ).

Comment: It's not the api problem, it is a design question. Anywary, you can survey other tool, such as Apache ZooKeeper for configuration management, or leveraging Message Queue, etc.

Comment: @Amith not a temporary table, but it should be kind of a table where you are maintaining your user details(i hope you are doing this), and then maintain a session id or something of that sort so that whenever user accesses any server, the server can check from the database that if the user is already logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use load balancer which redirects request as per server instance health, you can expose server health parameter by no. of connections that server have. for inter server communication i recommend to use apache activemq and shared database is also good idea